# Symfony 4.0 Unknown cache of type "array" configured for cache "result_cache" in entity manager "default"

Tags: symfony

Need help, I am getting this error while trying to update my composer.

**(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Unknown cache of type "array" configured for cache "result_cache" in entity manager "default".**

in DoctrineExtension.php line 735
at DoctrineExtension->loadCacheDriver('result_cache', 'default', array('type' => 'array'), object(MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
in DoctrineExtension.php line 757
at DoctrineExtension->loadOrmCacheDrivers(array('naming_strategy' => 'doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore', 'auto_mapping' => false, 'result_cache_driver' => array('type' => 'array'), 'mappings' => array('App' => array('is_bundle' => false, 'type' => 'annotation', 'dir' => 'C:\wamp64\www\pixcity/src/Entity', 'prefix' => 'App\Entity', 'alias' => 'App', 'mapping' => true), 'FrameworkBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SwiftmailerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SecurityBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'MonologBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DoctrineBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DoctrineMigrationsBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'WebProfilerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TwigBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DebugBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SensioFrameworkExtraBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'MakerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'WebServerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KMSFroalaEditorBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'LiipImagineBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KnpSnappyBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SverraestRevolutPHPBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DdeboerVatinBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TroopersAjaxBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TroopersMangopayBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true)), 'dql' => array('numeric_functions' => array('Rand' => 'App\Doctrine\Rand'), 'string_functions' => array('MONTH' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month', 'MONTHNAME' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month', 'YEAR' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year', 'DATE' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date', 'ACOS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos', 'SIN' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin', 'RADIANS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians', 'COS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos'), 'datetime_functions' => array()), 'query_cache_driver' => array('type' => null), 'metadata_cache_driver' => array('type' => null), 'class_metadata_factory_name' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory', 'default_repository_class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', 'quote_strategy' => 'doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default', 'entity_listener_resolver' => null, 'repository_factory' => 'doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory', 'hydrators' => array(), 'filters' => array(), 'name' => 'default'), object(MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
in DoctrineExtension.php line 396
at DoctrineExtension->loadOrmEntityManager(array('naming_strategy' => 'doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore', 'auto_mapping' => false, 'result_cache_driver' => array('type' => 'array'), 'mappings' => array('App' => array('is_bundle' => false, 'type' => 'annotation', 'dir' => 'C:\wamp64\www\pixcity/src/Entity', 'prefix' => 'App\Entity', 'alias' => 'App', 'mapping' => true), 'FrameworkBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SwiftmailerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SecurityBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'MonologBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DoctrineBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DoctrineMigrationsBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'WebProfilerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TwigBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DebugBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SensioFrameworkExtraBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'MakerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'WebServerBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KMSFroalaEditorBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'LiipImagineBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'KnpSnappyBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'SverraestRevolutPHPBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'DdeboerVatinBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TroopersAjaxBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true), 'TroopersMangopayBundle' => array('mapping' => true, 'is_bundle' => true)), 'dql' => array('numeric_functions' => array('Rand' => 'App\Doctrine\Rand'), 'string_functions' => array('MONTH' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month', 'MONTHNAME' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month', 'YEAR' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year', 'DATE' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date', 'ACOS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos', 'SIN' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin', 'RADIANS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians', 'COS' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos'), 'datetime_functions' => array()), 'query_cache_driver' => array('type' => null), 'metadata_cache_driver' => array('type' => null), 'class_metadata_factory_name' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory', 'default_repository_class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', 'quote_strategy' => 'doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default', 'entity_listener_resolver' => null, 'repository_factory' => 'doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory', 'hydrators' => array(), 'filters' => array(), 'name' => 'default'), object(MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
in DoctrineExtension.php line 359

**env configuration**

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        options:
            # PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND
            1002: "SET sql_mode=(SELECT 
        REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))"
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    result_cache_driver: array
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
    dql:
         numeric_functions:
             Rand: App\Doctrine\Rand
         string_functions:
             MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
             MONTHNAME: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
             YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
             DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
             ACOS: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos
             SIN: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
             RADIANS: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians
             COS: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos
```

Comment: Could you show your doctrine config?

Comment: Got the solution for this error. Its occurred due to updates in symfony, my version is old one and while running the composer update its pulled the updated bundles. So i just updated the versions and the issue is get solved.